Uncertainties in measurements widen the normal distribution.
In redistricting (gerrymandering) analysis, a state is divided into districts where district vote shares are written in terms of one of two parties, so if district #1 has a vote share of 40%, it means Party A has 40% of the vote and Party B has 60%. For a redistricting plan of K districts in a 50/50 state, the district vote shares tend to form a normal vote share distribution (VSD) around 50% with a width of $\sigma_{distribution}=14%$. But there is uncertainty in each district's vote share, so district #1 is treated as a normal distribution centered at 40% with an uncertainty of $\sigma_{district}=6$.
The problem is, adding the $\sigma_{district}=6%$ uncertainty to each district widens the entire VSD, and it widens it more after each election cycle where after ‘n’ cycles, the width becomes $\sigma_{distribution}=\sqrt{14^2+n \cdot 6^2}$.
How is this problem dealt with? I've searched, but don't know if there is a keyword I am missing. It has to appear in other fields. We know the VSD width, $\sigma_{distribution}$ , remains relatively constant over time but we also know there is uncertainty in the district vote shares, so is it possible to apply the $\sigma_{district}=6%$ uncertainty without widening the VSD? And to be clear, the VSD takes all kinds of shapes, but that does not matter because its standard deviation increases when $\sigma_{district}$ is applied.
One of the reasons for posting this concerns VSD shifts. For a normal VSD centered at 50%, each party gets 50% of the seats. Shifted to 51%, Party A now gets approximately $50+1/\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_{distribution}$ percent of the seats, so for $\sigma_{distribution}=14$ they get $52.85$%, and for $\sigma_{distribution}=\sqrt{14^2+6^2}$ they get $52.62$%. The wider the swing, the greater the difference between these numbers.

The variance of the sum of m independent random variables.is the sum of the corresponding m variances. That's why thre root (standard deviation) is $\sqrt{14^2+n \cdot 6^2}$
